# Django form ignores javascript validation

Tags: javascript, django, forms

I'm using a django form for my bookingsystem, inside a boostrap modal. 
In the form, I have used a onsubmit="return validateTime()" with a javascript-function that validates the time and returns false if its an illegal timeinput. When I test this by giving an illegal time, the alertbox pops up with the errormessage(and then returns false), but the form gets submitted and the modal closes.

```
<form method="post" id="createform" class="js-booking-create-form" onmouseover="checkStartTime()" onsubmit="return validateTime()">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="dayTitle"></h4>
    <button title="Close" type="button" id="close" class="btn" style="cursor: pointer" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    {% include 'booking/includes/partial_booking_form_calendar.html' %}
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button title="Click to create booking" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="cursor: pointer" >Create booking</button>
</div>
```

Is it just impossible to validate django forms with javascript functions or are there any small mistakes I'm doing? I didnt post the javascript function as I know it works and validates, but the form ignores it. 
I'm pretty new to django, so please dont slaughter me.

Comment: The code from `onsubmit` will be executed and form will be submitted anyway. You might want to implement `setCustomValidity` within your function and execute it on `oninput` event.

Comment: You could change you `<button>` to `<a href="myJavaScript()">` and include `document.forms.myform.submit();` when you want the form submitted.  I've not tested but I think it will work